# Unstable voltages in boost circuit

Tags: amplifier, boost

This is my first real circuit I've built. I've learnt a lot here, but have some problems that I don't quite understand.

It's pretty much just an over engineered alarm clock. The micro-controller running at 5 volts updates the display, and when the timer reaches 0, uses PWM to buzz the speaker. I wasn't happy with the volume at 5v, so I built an overkill boost circuit using the [LM2577-Adj](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2577.pdf) following the instructions provided. This created a much louder circuit that works really well, however I've currently got a bit of a feeling that this isn't the way to do it.

A simplified version of the circuit is shown below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7BfOI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(The 5V Arduino is acting a power supply right now, naturally will be replaced with batteries in the real deal, which is why I have [the regulator](https://www.pololu.com/product/2836) there.)

When the alarm started, the circuit restarted, I was able to fix that by sticking that (again overkill?) capacitor in there. It doesn't restart any more, however, the led display dims whenever the alarm is buzzing.

I don't have access to an oscilloscope, but I managed to rig something up to graph the voltage with the Arduino and a few voltage dividers.

The red, blue and green graphs are voltages measured at each of the marked locations on the circuit. This is a single pulse of the alarm. The part where the red goes crazy is the duration of the tone.

[image: Arduino Oscilloscope]

*(Please ignore the purple and orange, they were for debugging the makeshift oscilloscope itself.)*

I'm really confused by this. So I guess my question kind of is:

1. Why does the arduino voltage (green) drop and the circuit voltage (blue) rise when the alarm buzzes?
2. Why does the display dim when circuit voltage is high? My only thought is that it must be to do with how the TM1367 handles the higher voltage.
3. What could cause the sudden drop in levels for the amp (red) and the circuit (blue) and the sudden rise in the arduino voltage (green) part way through the alarm tone?

   Sometimes it happens earlier in the cycle, sometimes it doesn't happen, sometimes the arduino voltage is always higher than the circuit voltage. My hypothesis is that it's to do with the voltage regulator built into the arduino, but not sure what would have that kind of effect.
4. Is this the normal method of amplifying something like this? I assume not, but I don't know where to look to find the proper answer.
5. What's the worst that's going to happen beyond the dimming of the display? Anything else I should be worried about/do differently?

Comment: Why are you using a 5V regulator if your source is 5V? How much current can your 5V source supply? Where are the input and output caps on the voltage regulators?

Comment: @DanLaks As mentioned, in testing using the arduino as supply, will be switching to battery, hence the regulator. [This link here](http://robotics.lib-ieronimoub.gr/?p=715) suggests output current of 500mA. I'm not sure that's the problem cause I still get dimming of the LED display when running off battery.

Comment: @DanLaks By capacitor location, do you mean physical location? Caps for the LM2577 circuit I created are as close to the LM2577 as I could get them. In terms of the schematic I just followed the one provided in the documentation. For `C1` in the diagram is currently connected a bit of the way out with jumpers right now (yet to solder it in cause it wasn't part of the original plan). But it's closer to the 5V regulator than anything else.

Comment: You need a capacitor at the LM 2577 output to. Switching regulators do not deal well with fast current variation. Also, the total current is to high, only 2577 sucks at least 800mA when playing a sound. Adding the display consumption you might go over 1.5A  pololu max current.

Comment: Q1 will need a resistor in series with the base. Possibly 470 ohm.

Answer (score 2):

The voltage drop is because the power source is insufficient to operate everything at the same time.

Amplifier. no, it's not the normal method, but for low power systems it works well enough.  you only get one quarter of the output audio power from the speaker that could have got with a half-bridge drive, which may mean that you are using a more expensive speaker than you would otherwise need. and also you are using twice as much power as would be needed with a push-pull drive.

Connecting switching regulators in series can be problematic because they have negative resistance (higher supply voltage leads to a lower current draw) it's best to connect both regulators to the battery.

if you're building this thing out of modules, use one of those class-D amplifier modules to drive the loudspeaker, you'll probably get acceptable performance operating it from 5v.

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to see your physical setup, the following is a SWAG (Scientific Wild-Ass Guess).

> Why does the arduino voltage (green) drop and the circuit voltage
>   (blue) rise when the alarm buzzes?

The Arduino voltage is dropping because you are pulling a *lot* more current. With a speaker impedance of 8 ohms (and it may well be somewhat less), your nominal peak speaker current will be about 1 amp. This is mitigated somewhat since a 2N2222 simply won't pull that much, but still. As to the speaker voltage rising, I can't say. I suspect it's a reaction to the module getting warm. At any rate it appears to be be within "normal" range. I use quotes because the (standard crappy Chinese generic part) data sheet doesn't actually specify what the allowable output variation is.

And, just as a general tip - if your power supply is varying that much under load, you probably need to step to a bigger (more current capacity) supply. Just saying. If you don't, Murphy's Law says that at some point you're going to add another module and bring your system to its knees.

> Why does the display dim when circuit voltage is high? My only thought
>   is that it must be to do with how the TM1367 handles the higher
>   voltage.

At a guess, your ground wiring is too small and too long and you've daisy-chained your modules. The increased current on the return path is reducing the overall voltage at the display.

> What could cause the sudden drop in levels for the amp (red) and the
>   circuit (blue) and the sudden rise in the arduino voltage (green) part
>   way through the alarm tone?
>
> Sometimes it happens earlier in the cycle, sometimes it doesn't
>   happen, sometimes the arduino voltage is always higher than the
>   circuit voltage. My hypothesis is that it's to do with the voltage
>   regulator built into the arduino, but not sure what would have that
>   kind of effect.

Purely as a guess, your 2577 converter module is getting hot and a thermal protection feature is kicking in to save the regulator. This is consistent with my previous speculation.

> Is this the normal method of amplifying something like this? I assume
>   not, but I don't know where to look to find the proper answer.

Depends on what you mean by normal. A more conservative approach would be to get a separate 8 volt supply. Certainly if I were doing this I'd connect the boost converter to the "Arduino 5V" supply, rather than the buck-boost. That way, the buck-boost doesn't have to handle the extra current, which the other (5V) parts aren't using anyways. And if you're using the Pololu as insurance against variations in your 5 volt supply (and just why ARE you using it, anyways?) passing such variations along to your speaker won't have any great effect on its utility as an alarm clock.

And trying to get a lot of sound out of a speaker by driving it that way (large DC component of 4 volts) is not ideal - as long as cheap is not a synonym for ideal. It's probably fine for what you're doing, though. In general, though, speakers should be run with zero DC voltage. Otherwise they get hot and Bad Things happen.

I suspect that your wiring, particularly your ground, is a rat's nest of jumpers, and you should learn to provide a decent, low-impedance ground connection. Relatively thick wires, with each connection physically short and to a common point.

Also, you need decoupling capacitors, especially on your microcontroller - 0.1 uF ceramics are the classic starting point, with leads as short as possible.

A flyback diode across the speaker won't hurt, either.

And your speaker drive transistor, as mentioned, needs work. If you must use a bipolar transistor (just because you have them), you ought to put a base resistor in, although your microcontroller may have enough protection on its outputs to make this unnecessary. But it's a really good idea to get in the habit. If you use your "scope" to look at the collector voltage during operation, you'll almost certainly see that the collector is not getting very close to ground, which means your speaker voltage (and volume) are not what they should be. If you really want to handle this, go to logic-level MOSFETs, and be damned sure they are logic-level input. If not, your microcontroller output won't be enough to turn the FET on fully, and the result will be worse than using a 2N2222.